# Method that receives Object turn it into an existing pojo

Tags: java, spring, methods, casting, pojo

So, I have a pojo like this:

```
public class pojo {
   String name;
   String address;
   String email;

   // getter's and setter's here...
}
```

And with one method, that receives a type object, how do I turn it into the original type so I can user all getters and setters.

```
private void method(Object obj) {
   // use get's and set's from the original object of type "pojo"
   // instead of the methods from java.lang.Object
}
```

I don't really know how to explain it better, it's a little confuse to me. Wish you all understand.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**
So, i didn't explain it that well because i'm a little confused and I don't even know if what I want to do is possible. But, inside the method I want to somehow do something like this:

```
public void method(Object obj) {

   **Dynamically detect obj type** newObj = (obj type) obj;

   // I want to do like this, because this method will never know what 
   // object type I am passing.
   // I will have more than 10 pojo's and I wanted the method to detect
   // and create them dynamically.
}
```

Comment: How does "obj" look like?

Comment: It's just a  java.lang.Object @PhilippWilhelm. I'm trying to make this method dynamic, so it doesn't matter the type of the object he receives, he will always use the existing getters and setters from the pojo,

Comment: And what do you want to achieve with such a method? How would you call the methods if you don't know the type of the object?

Comment: @M.Deinum Because I have a method that creates a SOAP Envelope and I don't want to create the SOAPBody for each object type I have. Because if I have 100+ pojo's, I would need to replicate this method 100+.

Comment: And why aren't you just using Spring WS to send/create the envelope? Why are you even doing that yourself?

Answer (score 0):

you can use casting

here we create a Pojo object in an empty constructor,then we send it as an object to the method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Pojo pojo=new Pojo();
        pojo.method(pojo);
        System.out.println(pojo.getName());

    }
```

our method takes the obj which is a general java object and casting it as an Pojo object into test which is already a Pojo object (we do that so we could use the methods of the Pojo class).
then we setting it's a name.

```
public class Pojo {
    
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    
    public Pojo(){}
     
     public Pojo(String name,String address,String email)
     {
       this.name=name;
       this.address=address;
       this.email=email;
           
     }
     
     
     
     public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public void method(Object obj) {
        Pojo test = (Pojo)obj;
        test.setName("avi");
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but not really what I was looking for, I have edited the question so I can explain myself better.

Answer (score 0):

You must use casting.

```
private void method(Object obj) {
   Pojo p = (Pojo) obj;
  
   //Now you can use the pojo methods.
   p.getName(); //And other methods depending on what methods you have defined in Pojo
}
```

EDIT: Or you can use the [Java reflection API to get the name of the class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) and then use the appropriate casting.

To get the name of a class, use this:
`Class c = obj.getClass()`

You can then use a switch case to then use the appropriate casting.

Comment: Sorry, but not really what I was looking for, I have edited the question so I can explain myself better.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include information about using the Java Reflection API to get the class name

Answer (score 0):

Test with `instanceof` before cast.

Pojo pojo = obj instanceof Pojo? (Pojo) pojo : new Pojo();

Comment: Sorry, but not really what I was looking for, I have edited the question so I can explain myself better.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).

`Pojo pojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(object, Pojo.class)`

This converts your object to pojo type and hence all your methods within Pojo can be accessed.

Comment: Sorry, but not really what I was looking for, I have edited the question so I can explain myself better.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check with `instanceof` operator to detect the type of object.

if your intention is to create object dynamically, go for reflection to create object.

```
public void method(Object obj) throws Exception {

    Class<?> clz = obj.getClass();
    Object newObj = clz.newInstance();

    **Dynamically detect obj type** newObj = (obj type) obj;

    // I want to do like this, because this method will never know what 
    // object type I am passing.
    // I will have more than 10 pojo's and I wanted the method to detect
    // and create them dynamically.
}
```

since method return type is void, you must do your business logic inside that method, depending on different object type, you need to apply the business logic. then explicitly check object type to carry out your task within if block.